# Why is the operand receiving an error message from binary expression?

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm getting the following error:

> comparison between null and non-pointer (stream aka ('basic_fstream')and Null) invalid operands to binary expression (stream aka ('basic_fstream')and Null) and long')

Here is the code that's causing it:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[20][6];
    fstream dataFile("input.txt", ios::in);
    string input;

    int i,I=0;
    if (dataFile == NULL) // ERROR is on this line
    {
        cout << "can't open file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you why it can't process the expression. You can get the same result by using `if(!dataFile)`.

Comment: -1 For simply posting code and waiting for us to edit it into a reasonably question-looking format for you. If you're going to ask a question here on SO, please take the time to at least make it SEEM like you put some effort into it.

Comment: @Josh Don't say it intimidatingly!  user3874746 I +1'd you for including all the information, including the code, error message and the line on which the error happened.  However, please see [our revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24945002/revisions) for more what the expectations are for how a question is to be formatted in the future...

Comment: @HostileFork Roll back through the edits. This user literally copy and pasted their code into the question box and posted it, not even bothering to format. user3874746 has a valid problem, but how can he expect us to give him our time in solving his problem if he won't even take the time to ask it properly? I'm sorry if I'm coming off intimidatingly, but this is not a [new issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are following a tutorial that was written pre-C++11 and you are using a C++11 compiler. Before C++11, the stream classes had an `operator void*` conversion operator, where a null pointer would represent a bad state. In C++11, this was changed to an `explicit operator bool` conversion operator, which returns `false` if the stream is in a bad state. So you should change your `if` statement to:

```
if (!dataFile)
```

In fact, this has always been the idiomatic way to check the state of a stream (since it works pre-C++11 too).

Comment: @user3874746 That sounds like a separate problem. Is that the full linker error? Or does it say "Undefined reference to..." or something similar.